# React Native New Architecture - Redux & Hooks

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I've been developing apps using react native for a while now establishing my project architecture on redux, React.Component lifecycle and react-native-router-flux (for navigation).
Now, I need to start to develop a big new project which is going to be in production and needs to handle a lot of users. 
As I understand I cant keep using React.Compoent as my lifecycle and I need to implement the functionality of the new hooks system. 
My main concern is that react native with redux and hooks aren't stable enough and I won't be able to create a stable application.
As I see it I should use react-native with hooks, redux and react-navigation as my main architecture. I will be glad to get your opinion on this one.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All component in react can be defined as classes or function. It depends on you.

> As I understand I cant keep using React.Compoent as my lifecycle and I need to implement the functionality of the new hooks system

You can still use React.Component if you write component as classes. Use hooks if you write your component as function

> My main concern is that react native with redux and hooks aren't stable enough and I won't be able to create a stable application

Why do you know that they aren’t stable. I am using them on my production apps.

Basically, redux use for state management, react navigation for navigation. You could use hooks or not, it doesn’t matter